# No active vertices group for painting and aborting

Tags: rigging, vertices, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

So i was making a Vtuber rig here, when suddenly this pop up appear, and the character rig was all purple, at first i was like "Maybe it's because i join some of the separated part, i'll just unparent and parent it again" however it stayed like that no matter what, can someone help?

[image]

Comment: The error in itself means that you have no active vertex groups. Maybe show us the vertex groups you have on the model? even better if you could share the file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yLWjS9SkJjRnTuRKT9cO7I2GEJbH1ZQ3/view?usp=sharing okay here's the fbx file

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned it in the above comment, you're supposed to share it on https://blend-exchange.com/
I tried your link, but it's asking me to request access

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=6eSNSgbb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/6eSNSgbb/) hey sorry i just responded now, and happy new year here's the file hope it work this time